# Execute a init script from C++ program

Tags: shell-script, init-script, init.d, c++

I have a script in my `/etc/init.d/` which executes an application. I am able to start,stop and get status of the service from terminal. Now I would like to start the same service from my `C++` program. Is there any way other than using `system()` for this?

Thank you..

Comment: Sup with using system ?

Comment: If you don't want to use `system`, you can use `fork` and `execl`

Comment: Note that the whole `/etc/init.d/` machinery is vestigial, and will go away due to `systemd`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `fork()` and `exec()`

```
pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) { // child process
    execl("/etc/init.d/servicename", "/etc/init.d/servicename", "start", (char*) 0);
    perror("execl"); // only get here when exec fails
    exit(0);
} else if (pid > 0) { // parent process
    wait(NULL); // wait for child to finish
} else { // error
    perror("fork");
}
```

Comment: I dont know if it is a stupid doubt.. But what is the need of fork here? Why cant I call `exec` from parent process itself?

Comment: You need to fork if the C++ program needs to do something after starting the service.

Comment: Means to return to the execution of C++ program?

Comment: Yes, of course. `exec` replaces the program in the current process with the one you execute. So if the original program needs to keep running, it has to fork a child in which the new program runs.